# Storing data into Cassandra with a field of type List<Map<String, String>

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I need to store an object in Cassandra. It has a field of type `java.lang.String` and another field of type `java.util.List<Map<String, String>`. I am using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra version 2.1.6.RELEASE. I am getting the exception:

```
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Only primitive types are allowed
    inside Collections for property.
```

Is it possible to do that? If so can someone give me a complete example? Please specify the version of the libraries used.

Comment: this should be supported by Object Mapper in DataStax's Java driver... Spring Data Cassandra has limitations on nested collections

Comment: It would be quite helpful if I can have a reference to any such resource/example

Comment: Care to post the full stack trace? Note that this limitation was removed with Spring Data Cassandra 3.